# What is advantage of using serializer to save object in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Suppose I have a Model as follow:

```
class SampleUser(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Group(models.Model):

    members = models.ManyToManyField(SampleUser)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to know what are the advantage of using Serializers to create an object, lets say

serializers.py

```
class SampleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SampleUser
        fields = ('name','id','email')
```

views.py

```
serializer = SampleUserSerializer(data = request.data)
if(serializer.is_valid()):
    serializer.save()
```

than directly creating an sample user object

```
SampleUser.objects.create(....)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: And where is the `...` coming from on the second example?

Comment: @DanielRoseman By those dots I meant any parameter I want to put over there to create the object

Comment: Right. But how is it getting there? The point of the serializer is that it takes the POST data, validates it, and then creates the object. Otherwise, where do you get the data to create the object from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I will set parameters individually from request.data like `name=request.data["name"]` etc

Comment: But how is that better than using a serializer? And how will you verify that the data is valid?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I got your point. I am not saying that creating it via serialiser is not better but just wanted to know all the aspects in which it is better. One as you pointed out is validation, another is taking JSON directly. Anything apart from that in which it is better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191710/discussion-between-hardik24-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of simplicity, I am using the following model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

There are few advantages you can have while using the DRF Serializers

#### 1. Validation of data

As in your example, it is mandatory to call the [***`.is_valid()`***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) method before using the [serializer's **`save()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) method. That is, without validating the data, you can not write the data into the Database.
**Example:**
Suppose, you want to validate the `age` (age must be greater than 18) and `username` (only alphabetic are allowed), you can do that in the serializer, as

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_username(self, username: str):
        if username.isalpha():
            return username
        raise serializers.ValidationError("must be alphabetic")

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "age": {
                "min_value": 19
            }
        }
```

```
In [2]: data = {"username": "not a alpha", "age": 10, "name": "Foo"}                                                                                                                                               

In [3]: serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=data)                                                                                                                                                                  

In [4]: serializer.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[4]: False

In [5]: serializer.errors                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: {'username': [ErrorDetail(string='must be alphabetic', code='invalid')], 'age': [ErrorDetail(string='Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 19.', code='min_value')]}
```

**Note:** You can do these validations in [**`clean(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method of the model, but, it will not work with [***`.create(...)`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create) method, ***but only with the [models' `save(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method***

#### 2. Data manipulation

Suppose, the username must convert to *lower cases* before saving into the DB, we can do it by

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_username(self, username: str):
        if username.isalpha():
            return username.lower() # case conversion
        raise serializers.ValidationError("must be alphabetic")

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "age": {
                "min_value": 19
            }
        }
```

```
In [19]: data = {"username": "aBU", "age": 20, "name": "Arakkal Abu"} 
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                             

In [20]: serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=data)                                                                                                                                                                 

In [21]: serializer.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[21]: True

In [22]: dict(serializer.validated_data)                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[22]: {'username': 'abu', 'name': 'Arakkal Abu', 'age': 20}
```

#### 3. Ease of use with DRF

If you are using DRF, you must make use of the serializer. Serializers are *high-level* classes that provide many features by *abstract many things* from us. Which help us to complete many things in a few lines of code.

The combination of `serializers.ModelSerializer`, `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, and   `DefaultRouter` are making the CRUD API operations very easy as well as in a DRY fashion.

**Note:** If something I have missed here, feel free to comment.